# How to affect a single status in a where clause with multiple statuses

Tags: t-sql

Here's my query that returns a count of policies from year to date. I want to know how I can go about doing a case when statement that affects only the status that is equal to 'active'.

```
select distinct
count(pol3.CT_ID + pol3.CT_NSID) as 'YTD',
pol3.ct_status
from contract pol3
where (pol3.CT_Status = 'Quote' or pol3.ct_status='Active' or pol3.ct_status='Declined')
and Year(pol3.CT_Subscription_Date)>= datediff(year,(DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy,0,getdate()), 0)), getdate())
group by pol3.ct_status
```

Here's the current output:

[image]

I tried doing

```
select distinct
count(pol3.CT_ID + pol3.CT_NSID) as 'YTD',
pol3.ct_status
from contract pol3
where (pol3.CT_Status = 'Quote' or pol3.ct_status='Active' or pol3.ct_status='Declined')
and CT_ORIGINAL_QUOTE_ID is not null
and CT_ORIGINAL_QUOTE_NSID is not null
and Year(pol3.CT_Subscription_Date)>= datediff(year,(DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy,0,getdate()), 0)), getdate())
group by pol3.ct_status
```

This is obviously wrong because its targeting all three statuses. How do I go about making ct_original_* target only the active status? Any clues or pointers would be highly appreciated.

Comment: what should only take into account the active status? Your count?

Comment: I want to count all active policies that have data in original quote id and nsid basically but my filtering is also affecting my count of quote and declined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a CASE statement in the SELECT to return a 1 or 0 and then SUM the values returned.

```
SELECT pol3.ct_status, SUM(CASE 
    WHEN ct_status IN ('Declined','Quote') THEN 1 // all of these should count as one policy
    WHEN ct_status = 'Active' and CT_ORIGINAL_QUOTE_ID is not null and CT_ORIGINAL_QUOTE_NSID is not null THEN 1 // if data in ID and NSID and active count it
    ELSE 0 // all others count as nothing
    END)
from contract pol3
where (pol3.CT_Status = 'Quote' or pol3.ct_status='Active' or pol3.ct_status='Declined')
and Year(pol3.CT_Subscription_Date)>= datediff(year,(DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy,0,getdate()), 0)), getdate())
group by pol3.ct_status
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll have to tweak around with it to see if it works with everything else in the database.